# How to get all stories from instagram

Tags: android, post, instagram, charles-proxy

I am using an old version of instagram for android where I can listen to the SSL requests with Charles Proxy (on PC I did not).

When I get the stories `('feed/reels_tray/')` not all users have items.
For that it is necessary to send a POST to `'feed/reels_media/'` with all the ids (pks) and this returns the items of all.

But I can not form the post correctly. I always get the message:

```
"Message": "Invalid user list"...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This seems like an Instagram API support question. Are you able to form the request properly in Postman?

Comment: Are videos saved in some folder maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Here is instagram api to get feed list from user account

"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token="+USER_ACCESS_TOKEN

It get to post list from user account.

Comment: If i want to display story of following to login user than which api need to use?

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaツ
As far as I am aware the Instagram API does not currently return Stories.

Comment: In playstore there are lost of application which are fetch story from instagram but in instagram console console there is not mention of story api. @Mike

Comment: Is there any Api are you aware about it?

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaツ Yes in instagram developer console there in no endpoint define for stories api.
By using facebook graph api you can get stories of instagram business account.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/stories/

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaツ try this if it helps.
https://medium.com/@calialec/chrome-ig-story-bribing-the-instagram-story-api-with-cookies-c813e6dff911

Comment: Thanks a lot @/mike

Comment: Welcome :) @VishalPatoliyaツ

Comment: I want to to list of user which are posted story and after click on particular user i want  display all story of that user in my android application is it possible by using this?
@Mike

Comment: I have try a lot but didn't getting any solution for instagram stories , please help me.